# Can't we use sparkContext inside map function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to invoke the user defined function inside map as below,

```
df.select("path").map(x => func1(sparkSession, fs, path))

def func1(sparkSession: SparkSession, fileSystem: FileSystem, path: String)
{
  read HDFS file path and count the records.
}
```

with the above approach I am not able to read the files from HDFS. What is the real cause? Is it not possible to pass context to the function inside the map?

Comment: I guess thats not possible

Comment: Thanks Ramesh for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a high level, the `SparkSession` is the object that allows the driver to communicate with the executors. A `map` method, in contrast, defines a function that is going to be executed on the executors, meaning that it has to be serialized so that the executor can pick up the relevant data along with it and actually run it. You can imagine the hellish situations that could arise from having this object being serialized to the executors for their use.

In your case, if (as I can imagine) the number of paths is relatively moderate (think millions of them or less) you can collect those on the driver and then use those. Spark will take care to schedule this calls as necessary.

```
val paths: Array[String] = df.select.paths.as[String].collect()
for (path <- paths) {
  func1(sparkSession, fs, path)
}
```